# How to make shared Google Calendar event color same like original?

Tags: google-apps-script, colors, calendar, google-calendar-api

I use this code to add event in Google Calendar.

```
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("url");
 var createEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent("Requested : " + value[i][2]);
```

by default the color is yellow like below:
Below is my calendar.
[image]

Now whenever I triggered a code, the event color will change to green from yellow.

```
var a = cal.createAllDayEvent(legend + " : " +  getName);
  a.setColor("2");
```

It's working fine in my calendar, but why when I share with others, their color will remain both green. Below is my friend's calendar that I shared. Why that happen and how to make shared calendar event's color follow the original calendar's color?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Setting calendar and event colors only applies to a user's calendar view

In other words you cannot impose an event color on another user.

After all the other users might want to reserve the yellow color for a different calendar / event (e.g. their primary calendar).

If it is really important to you that all the other users see the event yellow, if you are a domain admin, you can set the event for all your domain users to the desired color by using a service account with domain-wide delegation.

However, this will not work for friends that are not part of you GSuite domain.